# Set minimum and maximum file size For file upload in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.0

how can i set minimum and maximum size for file upload in asp.net core 3?
i try to find Any way to fix this
On the Internet, I just found a solution to define the maximum size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, if you want to check the minimum and maximum file size For file upload, I suggest you could try to create a [custom middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to check the httpcontentlength, if the http content length doesn't match the minimum and maximum size, then you could return the custom response.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Add below middleware into the startup.cs Configure method:

Notice: I use app.usewhen to check the path, this will only work for the url path contains "api". If you want to match all the request, you could directly use `app.Use`.

```
            app.UseWhen(context =>
context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"),
CheckRequestLengthAsync);
```

CheckRequestLengthAsync method:

```
    private void CheckRequestLengthAsync(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.ContentLength <50 && context.Request.ContentLength > 5)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Not match the content length");
            }
            else
            {
                // Do work that doesn't write to the Response.
                await next();
                // Do other work that doesn't write to the Response.
            }


        });
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: i upload file from web page to api ,and file send As shown below (Request URL: data:image/jpeg;base64)

Answer (score 1):

Answer @brando-zhang Is write but need to Little fix

```
if (context.Request.ContentLength <10000 || context.Request.ContentLength > 200000)
```

allowed 10kb-200kb